# Is there a strategy for discrete control of a system with dynamics near sample rate?

Tags: discrete-signals, control-systems, theory, feedback

I'm trying to control a system where the controller sample rate is physically fixed and the plant has significant dynamics on the same order as the sample rate. I understand that one would prefer to have the sample rate considerably faster than the plant dynamics, but the physics of this system are such that this is inherently impossible. I can get some control of the system by hand-tuning a PID, but it seems considerably sub-optimal.

Is there a strategy for developing a controller like this?

Edit: I should add that the plant is this situation is a relatively complex LTI plant with reverberations caused by pure time delays. The delay cycles are a bit slower than the Nyquist frequency. The plant is stable.

Comment: not a good one.  if you have significant content above Nyquist, i think you might be screwed.

Comment: Do you have a model for the plant dynamics?

Comment: Would a low-pass-filter of sufficient order be able to suppress those dynamics?

Comment: Robert: There is some content above Nyquist, but the main dynamics I hope to address are between 0.1 and 0.5 Fs.

Comment: datageist: I have a model. It's a relatively complex linear system with reverberations due to pure time delays. The delay cycles are a bit slower than the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: fibonatic: a low-pass filter would be able to suppress the dynamics, but I also want fast response.

Comment: I am a bit confused, 0.1-0.5 Fs of "main dynamics" is not too bad and you can have a high order analog low pass to suppress anything above 0.5Fs. The difficulty is not so much about the 0.5Fs component but the mirror image will start "hurting" your 0.1-0.5Fs of bandwidth that you want to apply control to. Do you think you can share a bit more information about the problem?

Comment: High order analog filter means phase lag, which means small phase margin, low gain and slow performance. If you have a model and a stable system, use feed-forward...

Comment: I believe that for your type of system it is common to use an adaptive model and feed-forward. If your system can be accurately modeled, the performance should be very good. The adaptation minimizes the error, can be done offline (system ID) or online, but will not interfere with closed loop stability. Whatever you can squeeze out of your PID might help to reduce the model uncertainty a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your plant you might be able to do something. If the plant is unstable, but dominantly linear, you should be able to get a very accurate model using exact [discretization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization) (zero-order hold). Either you will be able to stabilize your plant using PID, or PID will be of too low order, in which case you need to switch to a control law matching you plant order. The H-infinity synthesis framework (robust control) will do that for you. Here you can also include uncertainty weights to limit control law gain, which might help esp. if your system is not linear. Depending on the uncertainty you might not be able to find a feasible control law for stabilization, however...

If your plant is stable, or stabilizable, you can further improve performance using feed-forward control. Here the sampling time should not be of much concern, and you can use something like [zero phase error tracking](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243782777_Zero_Phase_Error_Tracking_Algorithm_for_Digital_Control).

Comment: There is no such thing as exact discretization and zero-order hold is one of the worst you can do in terms of stability.

Comment: @percusse: how come it works in every single lab set-up I've ever done then?

Comment: Because you are not close to their sampling frequency.

Comment: @percusse: but I have been, still works

Comment: It cannot always work. It has no stability invariance properties and we spend at least 10 percent of our work in each project discretization of controllers. You can find examples of instabilities induced by discretizations with a google search

Comment: @percusse: Zero-order hold is an exact model of most DACs and ADCs, and will provice the most accurate descritption of a sampled system with such devices. Unless you have an exotic interoplating data-converter, ZOH is the only discretization method that will predict what will happen in both open and closed loop.

Comment: I think you are confusing sampling a signal and discretization of a system. But anyways, as you wish.

Comment: @percusse: So if you sample a continuous time system and that results in a discrete time system; that is not to be referred as discretization?

Comment: @percusse: what?  Can you include a link to the method you feel is inexact?  You must be talking of something different.  The ZOH method *is* exact in the sense that given an exact model of the continuous-time system (including an "exact" ZOH) the ZOH method exactly predicts how the plant will appear to the sampled-time controller.  You can even account for processing delays if need be.  Perhaps you're conflating inexact modeling in the continuous-time domain with inexact conversion to a discrete-time domain?